# What Star Trek humanoid species has the longest natural lifespan?

Tags: star-trek, aliens, biology

I don't mean due to advanced medical technology, cryogenics, stasis, time travel, etc.

I don't mean due to being a Q or a Borg or some other non-corporeal lifeform or a totally alien biology.

## Which ordinary biological humanoid species in *Star Trek* possesses the longest natural lifespan?

Comment: Suspected answer:   [El-Aurians](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/El-Aurian)?

Comment: By excluding "totally alien biology" aren't you simply limiting it to humans?   Otherwise it might be Trill.

Comment: Good question. :-)

Comment: @dvaeg: No, I'm differentiating between *totally alien biology* as contrasts to *ordinary biological humanoid*.   I.e. totally alien: Vorta, Q, 8472; ordinary humanoid: human, Klingon, Cardassian, El-Aurian, Kazon, etc.

Comment: @dvaeg:   Regarding the Trill:   The humanoid part of them is definitely not particularly long-lived, and the symbiont part counts as 'totally alien'.   So no.

Comment: Hard to say, but probably El-Aurians. Would the Trill even count? The symbiont is not humanoid, and the host body does not last forever. Jadzia Dax' body wouldn't have naturally lasted for hundreds of years, right? Also, we don't know how long the Cytherians naturally last, or, for that matter, Tamarians, Pakleds, or the Traveler (though the Traveler is probably not humanoid, since he can apparently shapeshift). Of known species, the answer is likely El-Aurians.

Comment: Is it appropriate to refer to non-physical beings (for instance, Q) as having an "alien biology?" It seems to me that "biology" implies creatures with cells and such, which Q, Organians, Thasians, etc., would surely not possess.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon, that is quite a pedantic distinction.   And anyhow,  I said *non-corporeal lifeform* or a totally alien biology.  So what's your beef?

Comment: I was referring to your comment, in which you gave Q as an example of "totally alien biology."

Comment: Where would you categorize "Flint" from TOS:"Requiem for Methuselah"? He was not merely humanoid but fully human (notwithstanding some unexplained biological aberration - "pierced through the heart and did not die"), and would have apparently remained immortal had he not left Earth.

Answer (score 8):

The [Gideons](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gideon) are humanoid and have become immortal as a result of the germ-free state of their homeworld (e.g. through natural evolution).

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I don't think it fits because it sounds like it's not really that they have an unusually long lifespan; they just have an extraordinary environment.    Within the confines of the story, it is to be understood that other humanoids placed in that environment would also be immortal?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - They appear to have evolved in such a way as to take advantage of the germ-free planet. Their plan is to import a germ-ridden human and thus return the ecosphere to something resembling normality.

Comment: Okay, but it's still not clear to me if we're talking about an ecosystem that evolved or whether the humanoids really have evolved to be unique.   Again, *Within the confines of the story, it is to be understood that other humanoids placed in that environment would also be immortal?*

Comment: @ThePopMachine - No, the implication is that it was something that occurred over time; "**HODIN:** *And so it was! A long, long time ago what we described was true! The atmosphere on Gideon has always been germ-free. And the people flourished in their physical and spiritual perfection. Eventually, even the life span increased. Death became almost unknown to us. It occurred only when the body could no longer regenerate itself, and that happens now only to the very old."*.

Comment: this seems to just say they don't get diseases,  only die of old age when they are "very old".  How old is that?

Comment: @thepopmachine - I read it that that don't die unless they get injured, and only then if they're already very old.

Comment: Well,  which is it?   I don't remember the episode at all.

Comment: @thepopmachine - Immortal unless killed seems pretty damn immortal to me

Comment: I honestly don't see how "[Death] occur[s] only when the body [can] no longer regenerate and that happens ...only to the very old" means that.   It seems to say that when you are very old, the body can't regenerate anymore and you die of old age.   I think the more likely interpretation is that 'regenerate' doesn't mean 'regenerate from an injury' but 'continually regenerate from slow degradation due to aging'.

Comment: @thepopmachine - I read it differently. Death only occurs after injury and old age. No injury, no death.

Answer (score 1):

[EL-Aurians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/El-Aurian) have a natural lifespan of at least 700 years (the canonical age of one minor character belonging to said species).

[Changelings](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Changeling) seem to be biologically immortal, but I doubt that they qualify for the "standard humanoid" category.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ba'ku](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ba%27ku) might count, although their longevity is apparently not due to anything inherent about their biology per se, but because

> They live on a planet that constantly regenerates them and reverses their aging. This process is shown to also work on Klingons (Worf) and Humans (Geordi), and so presumably would work on many, if not most, other humanoid species.

Comment: *"longest **natural** lifespan"*